Hiring organisation logo for the Google job Posting website is not showing
I am posting a job on google and it also getting shown inside the google search gallery but the issue is that the hiring organization logo is not showing? I have did a lot of R&D but still unable to find the reason for this issue. I have followed the google third party instruction and the image aspect ratio as well but the logo is still not showing. This is my Structured Data:
"hiringOrganization": {
  "@type": "Organization",
  "name": "Tkturners Pvt Limited",
  "sameAs": "",
  "logo":  "https://meetovo-file-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bilder/coach-image-cid-747-1714463199163-x7lbqr.png"
},

Job Search gallery Image:

Job Template Page Image:

My company logo image size is 200X200.

I tried google image size guideline. Rich test result is also getting
passed. Did a lot of R&D but same issue arises.

